# crear conexion tunel via ssh (JAVA) para digitar comandos en consola PUTTY

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

cordial saludo.

Tengo un inconveniente el cual no he podido solucionar, resulta que necesito automatizar un proceso el cual consta de una prueba de escritorio, el proceso es:

Ingresar al [putty](/questions/tagged/putty) con su respectivo host name y puerto, luego ingresar los datos de username y password, luego del ingreso digitar un comando.

Es algo muy breve, pero la verdad no he encontrado como hacerlo, ya he usado la libreria de Jsch para conexiones via SSH pero no encuentro la manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando esa libreria deberias hacer lo siguiente:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(usuario, host, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataIn));
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());

dataOut.writeBytes("mi comando\r\n");
```

Te dejo tambien un link a la misma pregunta del stackoverflow en Ingles por si te sirve tambien.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146991/running-telnet-command-on-remote-ssh-session-using-jsch