# Java hibernate crear tunel ssh

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ssh

He estado mirando y la verdad que no he encontrado nada que me ayude. Tengo una aplicación de escritorio en java-hibernate que se conecta a servidor mysql en remoto. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el acceso al servidor lo tengo que autorizar mediante ip.
El problema es cuando me cambia la ip, he visto que se puede crear un tunel mediante [jsch](/questions/tagged/jsch) pero por más que leo no se como hacerlo. No se que poner en cada campo de los ejemplos que he visto.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Un `tunel ssh` con `jsch` no te va a servir porque también necesita `host` (`ip`) y `puerto`, como puedes ver [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72802/3834). Lo que tienes que hacer es que al servidor donde te quieres conectar debes declararle un `dominio`, y en tu aplicación debes conectarte poniendo el `dominio` no la `ip`. De este modo si la `ip` cambia no importa porque tu apuntas al [dominio](http://www.ipv6.mx/index.php/informacion/noticias/1-latest-news/295-declaracion-de-servidores-en-ipv6-para-dominios-mx). Para declarar un `dominio` debes [modificar el archivo hosts del equipo](https://www.adslzone.net/redes/windows/como-modificar-correctamente-el-archivo-hosts-de-windows/), a veces tarda en tomar la configuración como 15 minutos.